# How can I center this Wordpress navigation?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes, styling

The theme author isn't helping and I've tried tweaking the CSS to the nav, containers, the ul - nothing is working. Could I get some help?

http://bit.ly/1jQdCrr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify width for your top naviagtion and set margin. Please try below.

Make this change in your **style.css**

```
#main-navigation ul {
   margin: 0px 0 0 0;
   padding: 0px 0;
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 865px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Hope this helps